# Preserve date tooltip when moving between year and month parts

Tags: feature-request, question-statistics

If a date consists of multiple parts, e.g. years and month, can you add tooltips for both? At the moment the user is tempted to move the mouse between the parts and the tooltip goes away and does not reappear for the other part

[image]

Example question to test: [Beamer template with different style options for frames](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173201/beamer-template-with-different-style-options-for-frames)

<sub>(I moved the part about adding a tooltip to the view count to [Add tool tip for view count](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331371/237989) because comments/answer made me realise that these are in fact different issues and not both caused by the problem of a missing tooltip like I first thought. I thought of moving the part about the date to a separate question and leaving the view count here, but this would have invalidated an existing answer. I'd like to apologise to the users who voted for the view count issue!)</sub>

Comment: Perhaps I'm reading your question wrong, but I can't reproduce this in Chrome or Edge. It seems the months portion *does* have a tooltip already. (I agree wholeheartedly that viewed should have a tooltip tho)

Comment: @scohe001 I can reproduce with both firefox and safari

Comment: Windows 10 and Chrome 75 and a tooltip shows on the months part for me too.

Comment: most importantly, bring back the views count tooltip !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! (imagine I wrote this in capslock).

Comment: @samcarter it's unfortunate that you lumped together the two issues.  people will get distracted by the first, from the second. :( and the tooltip was there before the change, so it's definitely a **bug**.

Comment: @WillNess I will remove the month part

Comment: you can't do it now, that it got answered. :) maybe re-ask with the second issue only, separately? (and tag it "bug")?

Comment: @WillNess I think this might be unfair towards the users who most probably voted because of the view count

Comment: the loss from two issues being lumped together is IMO bigger than the loss for the few upvoters. there's real chance for the bug to go unnoticed, as it is now.

Comment: As suggested in comments, I moved the part about the view-count to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331371/add-tool-tip-for-view-count

Comment: @scohe001 See my answer below on how to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is partly an inconsistency issue and partly a browser bug.

I am using Windows 10, FF 67.0.4

---

`Asked 5 years, 3 months ago` seems like a browser bug as the `title="2014-04-24 09:50:44Z"` wraps around the entire text but as you move your cursor from left to right then the tooltip goes away and the only way to re-active it is to completely move your mouse off of the element and re-enter it.

---

`Active today` applies `title="2019-07-25 14:26:09Z"` only around "today" so it works properly.

---

`Viewed 3k times` has no tooltip and it definitely should have one once the counter get simplified; presumably at `1k`?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: If I would ask a new question about this (as suggested in comments) , would you move your answer there?

Comment: there's no need to move it, I think, if you make this question about the first issue, and ask new question about the views number bug. :) @samcarter

Comment: @samcarter Sorry, I was at lunch. I think you could have easily changed your title to "Question stat inconsistencies", applied the `bug` tag, and called it a day but it looks like you've already decided to break things out...