# Add tool tip for view count

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, question-statistics

Please add a tool tip to the view count that shows the exact number

[image]

(this was also possible in the old view in the side bar)

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331354/162102

Comment: actually, why not just print the whole number, as was done before?

Comment: Twitter, YouTube, Instagram , everybody follows this number abbreviation trend. At least, StackExchange does not adapt to circular profile pictures. …yet… @WillNess

Comment: @neverMind9 Really? ***Instagram***? If we wanted to be on Instagram we'd be on Instagram.

Comment: @WillNess I did not intend to compare the purposes and target audiences of the sites directly, I am just saying that many platforms on the internet are following that rounded trend. Rounded UI, rounded numbers, rounded profile picture, rounded everything.

Comment: @neverMind9 yes, and I am saying, it's not relevant. we are not being removed scientific observers here studying and discussing various trends in social platforms (or what have you); we are active participants in one of them. BTW I come from more STEM-oriented StackOverflow; you could be from movies or what have you (I didn't check); so naturally we - as also our communities in general - might have different preferences. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've merged adding the exact number of views to the title attribute of that section. It'll go live in the next build.

Comment: How often do builds happen, out of interest?

Comment: Thank you very very much!

Comment: is already working. thanks. what about showing the whole number to begin with, so no tooltip is needed? it was shown in full before, on the side. could it be done?

Comment: (at)Aaron Never on mobile, I always want just the exact number for the views, or none at all. Hovering for a tool tip is just a hassle for this and still lost functionality for me. So, seconding @Will Ness, what shall I do now? I already upvoted the comment here. Shall I open a full feature request for this? Or is this already said and (not) done – on purpose?

Comment: (I meant the tooltip is working. the number of views is still abbreviated).